# Why does a property get initialized to a null instead of an empty list from configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net-core web api project with a configuration containing the following definition:

```
"MyClass": {
   "Value1": 1,
   "Value2": []
}
```

This configuration is used to initialize the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int[] Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

This class is initialized from configuration using the following code in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<MyClass>(Configuration.GetSection("MyClass"));
    services.AddSingleton<AService>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

My service constructor looks like this:

```
public FeedbackRetrievalService(IOptions<MyClass> myclass)
{
    _myclass = myclass;
}
```

In the constructor I notice that `Value2` is `null`, even though it does appear in the configuration as an empty list - which is the value I would expect the property to be initialized with. I expected that the property would be initialized with `null` only when the field is missing from the configuration. Is there any way with which I could initialize the field as an empty list?

Comment: You could create logic inside the setter of `Value2` so that a `value` of `null` resolved to an empty list instead.

Comment: Maybe try dynamic collection like IList, IEnumerable instead of [].

Comment: @DiskJunky -  That is definitely a much more elegant solution than what I have now but I'm wondering if there's anyway to do this straight from the configuration

Comment: @PrzemekMarcinkiewicz - Same behavior for Lists

Comment: @DiskJunky The setter of `Value2` will *never* be called though if the configuration contains an empty array. See my answer below for an explanation.

Comment: @poke good to know but easily resolved but having a default empty array for the property. Moot though, your answer is thorough :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that the JSON configuration *loader* and the configuration *binder* are two separate components. When you load a configuration, the configuration provider will load the whole configuration file into a key/value structure where the key is a *property path*. In your example, `MyClass:Value2:0` and `MyClass:Value2:1` could be paths for two array elements in your `Value2` JSON array.

The configuration *binder* will then later interpret that structure and turn it into an object of your class. At that time, it will only have the information available that exists in that key/value structure that was previously loaded.

Now, if you look at the loaded configuration before binding it, you will notice that an empty array does not result in anything. And if you think about how the path works, it makes sense: `MyClass:Value2:0` and `MyClass:Value2:1` are the values for index 0 and 1 respectively of the `Value2` array. But how would this work for an empty array? There simply isn’t an entry for an empty array.

So since the empty array does not appear in the loaded configuration, the binder cannot initialize your array.

What you can do however is set up default values for bound configuration types:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int[] Value2 { get; set; } = Array.Empty<int>();
}
```

Now, if you bind your configuration with that empty array to that type, the `Value2` will never be touched by the binder, leaving its default value intact.

Comment: This is a great thorough answer. The thing that bothers me is that if I completely remove Value2 from the configuration the field will still be an empty array instead of null.

Comment: Yeah, but it is pretty impossible to figure out which is the case at runtime, since either way the keys are missing.

Comment: @MaorVeitsman You have to keep in mind that there are many different configuration provider available which all are required to produce the same key/value format. So you simply cannot map *all* the semantics that are possible in one format since there simply wouldn’t be an equivalent in the others. – If this bothers you and you need to differentiate a missing value from an empty array, chances are that you are making your configuration far too complicated.

Comment: @poke Thanks for the explanation. Came across this post when debugging an issue. 
One thing that I found is that if the value of the array is not empty in the configuration and we use public int[] Value2 { get; set; } = Array.Empty<int>(); It'll always be empty when it's bound. I assume this is because the value in the object is already initialized.

Comment: @lopezbertoni That does sound wrong since the configuration value _should_ be properly bound to the property (even if it already exists). Can you try using a `List<int>` instead of an array here? Maybe the binder was changed not to extend existing arrays.

Comment: @poke
The example I have is the following:

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
           MyList = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> MyList {get; set; }
}
When binding this, the list is always empty. Even when it's configured properly. Once we removed the initialization from the constructor, it worked as expected.
Thanks for taking the time to answer!